# JQuery File Upload plugin Delete button not working after changing upload directory

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

In the Blueipm JQuery File Upload plug-in, I want files to upload into their own directories.

I've added options to upload files into new directories, which appears to work fine on upload, but the Delete button now does not work properly. The uploaded file is removed from the web-page, but not from the server.

I've tried adding an option for 'delete_url' (and even delete_dir), but that doesn't work. Here is the entire index.php file:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); 

require('UploadHandler.php');

$newUploadDir = "files/" . microtime(true) . mt_rand() . "/";

$options = array(
    'upload_dir'=>$newUploadDir, 
    'upload_url'=>'server/php/' . $newUploadDir;
)

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

It'd be great if someone'd be kind enough to help solve this one.

P.S. can I add the maxChunkSize option in this way, and what would be the file size limit in Chrome with a 10MB chunk size limit?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but still worth an answer.  I was working today with a C# version of the PHP uploader and tried to append a session ID where you are putting a time.  I ran into the same problem.

It's been a year, so the first thing to try would be to update the plug-in **and** the upload handler... see if that resolves the problem.

If not, or if you stay with the older version, you will have to track how the *upload_dir* variable changes within the upload handler, from the constructor to the *delete* function.  It looked to me that the only change the author expected people to make would be changing the name of the directory (e.g., from "files" to "uploads"), but not appending a sub-directory.

The fact that the files do not get deleted on the server but do on the client strongly suggests that the delete function does not work on the correct directory but a proper json response is returned.

From [this page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-user-directories), you should be able to set the option user_dirs to true and then override the get_user_id method to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I made DELETE works.
Here is my solution: (server/php -index and UploadHandler)
$myPath is the dinamic directory
index.php :

```
    $upload_dir = full path of $myPath
    $upload_url = full url of $myPath
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
    'upload_dir' => $upload_dir
    'upload_url' => $upload_url
    'myPath' => $myPath,
    )); //I created a new option 'myPath'
```

UploadHandler
search set_additional_file_properties

```
    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
            $file->deleteUrl = $this->options['script_url']
                .$this->get_query_separator($this->options['script_url'])
                .$this->get_singular_param_name()
                .'='.rawurlencode($file->name)
                .'&myPath='.$this->options['myPath'];
```